# Login to admin give this error

Tags: admin-panel

Error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:85:"Unknown number format type 'boolean'. Format '' must be a valid number format string.";i:1;s:3808:"0 lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php(307): Zend_Locale_Format::_checkOptions(Array)
1 lib/Zend/Currency.php(194): Zend_Locale_Format::toNumber(0, Array)
2 app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(270): Zend_Currency->toCurrency(0, Array)
3 app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(242): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatTxt(NULL, Array)
4 app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(222): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatPrecision(NULL, 2, Array, true, false)
5 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Bar.php(82): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->format(NULL)
6 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Bar.php(62): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar->format(NULL)
7 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Totals.php(74): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar->addTotal('Revenue', NULL)
8 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Totals->_prepareLayout()
9 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
10 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard.php(50): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...')
11 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard->_prepareLayout()
12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
14 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
15 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
16 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
19 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
20 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(40): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
21 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
22 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
23 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
24 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
25 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
26 index.php(96): Mage::run('', 'store')
27 {main}";s:3:"url";s:70:"/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

How to solve this problem??

**EDIT**

```
<config>
<global>
    <install>
        <date><![CDATA[Wed, 01 Oct 2014 08:15:12 +0000]]></date>
    </install>
    <crypt>
        <key><![CDATA[xxxxxxxx]]></key>
    </crypt>
    <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
    <resources>
        <db>
            <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
        </db>
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[xxxxx]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[xxxxxx]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[xxxxxx]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[xxxxxx]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
    </resources>
    <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: Are you using memcached ?

Comment: No i m moved my code to another server

Comment: post your url .

Comment: Could you post the content of your app/etc/local.xml file (removing the database credentials obviously ;) )

Comment: Did you change the base urls in your database ?

Comment: yes i changed..